# Setting UTF-8 locale for python in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, utf-8, locale

On an Ubuntu 12.04 VM (set up using vagrant and the `hashicorp/precise64` box), my locale says that I have the `UTF-8` language, but python is getting a `latin-1` environment.

Here's what I'm seeing:

```
vagrant@vagrant:~$ locale                                                                                                                                 
LANG=en_US.UTF-8                                                                                                                                          
LANGUAGE=                                                                                                                                                 
LC_CTYPE="en_US"                                                                                                                                          
LC_NUMERIC="en_US"                                                                                                                                        
LC_TIME="en_US"                                                                                                                                           
LC_COLLATE="en_US"                                                                                                                                        
LC_MONETARY="en_US"                                                                                                                                       
LC_MESSAGES="en_US"                                                                                                                                       
LC_PAPER="en_US"                                                                                                                                          
LC_NAME="en_US"                                                                                                                                           
LC_ADDRESS="en_US"                                                                                                                                        
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US"                                                                                                                                      
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US"                                                                                                                                    
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US"                                                                                                                                 
LC_ALL=en_US                                                                                                                                              
vagrant@vagrant:~$ python                                                                                                                                 
Python 2.7.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:58:35)                                                                                                             
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2                                                                                                                                     
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.                                                                                    
>>> print u'\u1f41'                                                                                                                                       
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                        
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>                                                                                                                     
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character u'\u1f41' in position 0: ordinal not in range(256)
```

How can I get a true utf-8 system environment for python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The locale for `LC_CTYPE` ought to be `en_US.UTF-8` in `locale` output. Try

```
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

and if it does not work (as in `LC_CTYPE` set explicitly), also:

```
export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Comment: however I still wonder why it is not set so by default... maybe your SSH is sending wrong locale over

Comment: When I first provision the VM, when I ssh in, the first command in the bash history is `sudo locale-gen en_US`. I wonder if it has anything to do with this?

Comment: Ok, so make a new answer of it and accept it instead ;)

Comment: It's the answer to your wondering, not to my question. Your answer is quite sufficient!

Comment: but it is not the true solution! :D